# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: [] while Creating and OpportunityShare

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {
    
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        List<User> lstUser = [Select Id,isActive From User Where isActive = true And (Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' OR Profile.Name = 'Standard User')];
        System.debug('lstUser:::>'+lstUser);        
        List<OpportunityShare> sharesToCreate = new List<OpportunityShare>();
        for (Opportunity oOpportunity : Trigger.new) { 
            if(lstUser != null && lstUser.size() > 0){
                for(User oUsers : lstUser){
                    OpportunityShare oOpportunityShare = new OpportunityShare();
                    System.debug('UserId:::>'+oUsers.Id);
                    oOpportunityShare.UserOrGroupId =  oUsers.Id;
                    System.debug('oOpportunityShare.UserOrGroupId :::>'+oOpportunityShare.UserOrGroupId);
                    oOpportunityShare.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
                    System.debug('oOpportunityId :::>'+oOpportunity.Id);
                    oOpportunityShare.OpportunityId = oOpportunity.Id;
                    sharesToCreate.add(oOpportunityShare);
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        if (!sharesToCreate.isEmpty()){
            insert sharesToCreate;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sharing Opportunities to all users via Apex instead of using a Criteria-Based Sharing Rule or simply changing your Org-Wide Defaults?

Comment: @DavidReed I have a requirement to share Opportunities to all users then revoking the access from the selected users in a custom object which is on Detail side of the Opportunity.

Comment: don't create a share for the Opportunity owner; also, by definition, `lstUser` will never be null or empty

Comment: There are _lots_ of reasons that this can happen, but I would guess that here it's because a user is creating an Opportunity on an Account to which they have only Read record-level access. Might that be the case? Can you [edit] to provide more reproduction details?

Comment: I'm also _really_ suspicious of that sharing architecture and I don't think it's going to work very well, but that's a topic too big for this format.

Comment: @DavidReed Currently the Opportunity is not attached to any Account so I don't think this should cause an error

Comment: @cropredy Thanks it helped

Answer (score 2):

So, this error occurs when you try an do an explicit share to the record's owner.  So, you can rewrite your trigger to be ..

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {
    
    
  Map<Id,User> usersById= new Map<Id,User> (
                    [Select Id, IsActive 
                        From User 
                        Where isActive = true And 
                              Profile.Name IN ('System Administrator','Standard User')]);
  List<OpportunityShare> sharesToCreate = new List<OpportunityShare>();
  for (Opportunity oppo: Trigger.new) { 
    for(Id shareWithUserId: usersById.keySet()){
       if (oppo.Ownerid = UserInfo.getUserId()) {continue;} // don't share to owner
       sharesToCreate.add(new OpportunityShare(
               UserOrGroupId =  shareWithUserId,
               OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit',
               OpportunityId = oppo.Id));
     }
   }   
        
  insert sharesToCreate; // no need to test for empty as empty collection doesn't burn DML
        
}
```

*Note: There is a possibility that you'll exceed # DML recs per Transaction (10,000).
200 Oppos and 50 eligible users = 10,000. If that is a realistic possibility, then you'll need to delegate work to a chained set of Queueables*